# It's possible to write api rest automated test using webdriverIO and chai-http?

Tags: rest, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io, chai-http

I'm trying to use `webdriverIO` to make automatic test over an API rest without any result, also try with `chai` and `chai-http` using `webdriverIO`, but nothing yet. Any clue?

This is something I wrote:

```
  var chai = require('chai');
  var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
  global.expect = chai.expect;
  chai.Should();
  chai.use(chaiHttp);

  var username = 'salvador.salvatierra@alegra.com';
  var token = 'a5ff7f1063582fd0140d';

  describe('Se consulta a la lista de contactos a traves de la API rest', 
 function(){

   it('Se hace un request GET al endpoint /contacts', function(){

    chai.request('https://app.alegra.com/api/v1/contacts')
    .get('/')
    .set('Accept','application/json')
    .query({limit:'10', order_direction: 'DESC', order_field: 'id'})
    .auth(username,token)
    .then(function(res){
        console.log(res);
        res.should.have.status(200);
        res.body.should.be.a.json;
    })
    .catch(function (err){
        setTimeout(function(){
            throw new err;
        });         
    })      
});

});
```

**UPDATE**:
I'm using `webdriverIO` with `mocha`, `chai` and `chai-http`. The way I'm running this is `.\node_modules\.bin\wdio wdio.conf.js --spec .\test\specs\test\get_test.js` via command and the browser command I'm using is `browser.url('/invoices')`. The endpoint I want to hit is `https://app.alegra.com/api/v1/contacts/`

This is my `package.json`:

```
 {
  "name": "web-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "\"# Alegra webdriverIO tests\"",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "chai": "^4.1.1",
    "chai-http": "^3.0.0",
    "chai-webdriverio": "^0.4.2",
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "supertest": "^3.0.0",
    "wdio-dot-reporter": "0.0.8",
    "wdio-mocha-framework": "^0.5.11",
    "wdio-selenium-standalone-service": "0.0.8",
    "wdio-spec-reporter": "^0.1.2",
    "webdriverio": "^4.8.0"
   },
   "scripts": {
     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
   },
   "author": "Salvador Salvatierra",
   "license": "ISC",
   "directories": {
     "test": "test"
   },
   "repository": {
   "type": "git",
   "url": "git+https://ssalvatierra@bitbucket.org/ssalvatierra/alegra-wdio.git"
   },
  "keywords": [
    "alegra",
    "test",
    "webdriverio"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://bitbucket.org/ssalvatierra/alegra-wdio#readme"
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Your question looks much better now. Don't you have to invert the order or your call to be `var get = chai.request('<your_url>').auth(user, pass).get('partial_url')`?

Comment: @Tom when i change the code like `var get = chai.request('https://app.alegra.com').auth(username,pass).get('/invoice');` I got an .auth is not a function error.

Comment: How do you run your code? Are you using also Jasmine? What is the var `browser`? Can you provide any `package.json` for your example? Please add all information you can in the question.

Comment: I already update the information @Tom

Comment: @Salvador, your package code has an extra comma, so it gives syntax error. After fixing that and runnign `npm install`, it says `npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer chai-webdriverio@0.4.2 wants chai@~4.0.1`. Are you sure all the information in the question is correct?

Comment: @Tom, that was just a part of it, I just uptate the package.json

Comment: I added the callback function so I can get the http response, now when i run the test and it should appear an error, for some reason the error it is not recognize, for example erase the auth part, the test should get to the throw new error part and show me the error in res, but this dont happend, any clue?

Comment: @iamdanchiv do you know something about this?

Comment: @Tom i just change the code, this run really good, but now I cannot get the errors when there is no 200 status, if you comment the ".auth" line and run this you will see that it run good, it shouldnt run good because it never find the 200 status code

Comment: @robertklep can you help with this?

Comment: I heard that Selenium aims at testing web UI. The Node API request = require('http') has ways of sending HTTP requests. Postman appears to simplify regression bookkeeping.